# Is it possible to declare a pair that contains a pointer to a similar pair

Tags: c++

I am looking for something like:

```
pair<int, pair<int, ...>*>*> p;
```

Is it possible to declare such pair? Is there already a data structure for this?

Comment: `pair` and templates are C++ features. Do not tag C for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
struct A
{
    std::pair<int, A *> p;
};
```

You could also inherit from the pair, but I wouldn't do it to keep the code simpler.